# Set Time Limit to Expire ASP.NET Website C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website developed in ASP.Net & C#
and this source code is given to my client...

Is any way so that **after one Year it will expire and His is not able to use it**...& *its hidden from him some where secure..*

Please Help me out....

Comment: Simply accompany the source code with the respective contract that you and the client sign in which the licence agreement and the terms of use are clearly stated. Make sure to validate them by your lawyer.

Comment: If you don't like or trust your client, you should search for a new one instead of giving him phony software which might lead to a legal issue.

Comment: why would you give the source code to your client if you don't want them to use it after a given time period? Whatever you do (hiding stuff in dll or communicate to another web server to get some info), the client will be able to bypass anything with the source code. Either make a good contract or don't give source code as Darin said.

Answer (score 0):

I am with Darin. But I have a solution.  add a sqlite database to your app. Add fields in that sqlite database regarding the start date of the application and end date for the application. Create a program (dll)to extract the information from the sqlite database and perform the operations according to your need. Call that dll method in App_Start in global.asax file. Be sure that the one cannot be able to obfuscate the dll.

Might this help.