# how to Expire Java Application After 1 year?

Tags: java

How to expire Java Application after one year though client have source code with them ?
some where secretly  ?
so he is not able view & change it..?

Comment: LOL, what?  Why would you do this?

Comment: If the client has all the source code, this will be very tricky...

Comment: And what has it got to do with servlets or jsp?

Comment: Send over a big dude with a stick and say "pay your licensing fee or the server gets it in the eye."

Comment: Does the client know you're intending to do this, or are you going to be in breach of contract for even trying?

Comment: could you precompile the jsp's and therefore not deliver them?

Comment: some near duplicate to this one here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552162/set-time-limit-to-expire-asp-net-website-c-sharp

Comment: add enough bugs. They will come back to you for fixes..

Answer (score 11):

There is no technical solution to this, it's completely impossible. If you have a contract that says the client may only use the application for one year, then you can sue them if they still use it afterwards. If you do not have such a contract, don't even try this, as it might leave *you* open to be sued for damages.

Using the right tool for the job also means not trying to find a technological solution to a legal problem.

Comment: there's a trivial technological solution to this kind of legal problem: add some server-side check. There's an entire industry of "licensing managers" that basically work by mandating an Internet access and by performing online license verifications.  Some go further and make part of the computation happen on the server side (and there's no way around that unless an attacker tries to re-write the logic that happens on the server-side).  For example I've paid $$$ for a special C++/BREW compiler that was protected by FlexLM if I remember correctly (it was a long time ago).

Comment: @user988052: if the client has the application's source code, it will be equally trivial to remove that check. Putting a non-trivial part of the application logic on a server controlled by you is pretty much the only thing that works, but requires the application to be designed that way.

Comment: @user988052 Michael's absolutely correct there - any kind of "Is this still allowed to run?" check is completely useless. Instead of changing the code you can also just monitor the packages sent and then forward the client checks to your own server that always returns "Well yes everything's alright". The only way is to store a large part of the applications logic on the server side because in that case you have to rev engineer that part..

Comment: @Voo: first Michael didn't talk at all about any *"is this still allowed to run"* checks in his answer, so you're commenting to a comment he made *after* I posted my own comment : )  My point is: it's not true that there's some sort of fatality making software impossible to copy, even if you have 99% of its source code.  I've both written online license managers protection and paid $$$ to license software protected by such license managers.  It's a very real technology (and there are companies that do *only* that) and I don't buy the *"there's nothing we can do"* fatalistic/resigned approach.

Comment: @Voo: as a mostly unrelated sidenote nowadays I also work on commercial webapps which not only is the new trend but which is also a very good way to prevent people from running unlicensed versions of your software : )

Comment: @user988052 Well it seemed - and still seems - to me that we're talking about client side checks here. If you're writing webapps or anything that has large part of its logic on server side, you can solve the problem technically - rather simple even. But if you don't, any license manager is just a waste of time and money - even worse, most (actually all I've had to use from large companies) of these license managers lead to horrible user experiences for the paying users. And I rather doubt that a C++ compiler would work very well as a webapp for example.

Comment: @Voo: I was also talking about server side checks (and so did you in your first comment) but anyway...  You consider it a waste of time money but the thruth is: even the simplest copy protection will prevent 99% of your customers from pirating your software.  A copy protection like FlexLM is not meant to resist to the best pirates: it's meant, as the saying goes, *"to keep honest customers honest"*.  You consider it a waste but I can tell it's a very successful industry protecting *very* successful and very advanced products.

Comment: @Voo: and if you think server-side compilation ain't working you're wrong. I've worked on mobile porting solutions where our customers couldn't make their builds without having part of the build/compilation being performed on our servers. We were doing it for BREW builds, so that people buying our software could benefit from the $$$ BREW compiler, that we were in a way re-licensing to them (it was fully allowed by the compiler's license). So we were paying a product (using FlexLM as a protection) and we were then doing our client's build on our servers.  It's not a black&white world...

Comment: @user988 That's getting a bit OT, but what I mean with "server side checks [check really not being the best word here]" is more than returning a boolean value to your client - we're talking about doing a non trivial amount of real work on the server side. About DRM: People who want to pirate successful software aren't going to start windbg - they're going to google "AppX torrent" or whatever so if one pirate cracks your software you've already lost (and if the software is interesting enough someone will do it). Imo, the solution to this is not invent another layer of DRM, but

Comment: offering a better experience to the customers and good support. Much better than having to tell your paying customers why they can't use truecrypt with your program installed (did FlexLM fix that finally?). There are enough examples of this around that show how good this can work: steam, the music industry,.. And lots of examples of consumer backlash because of ridiculous DRM. PS: Note that I said "webapp" not server side compilation, I'm currently SSHed into a cluster to run some verilog programs so I'm quite certain that works fine :)

Comment: @Voo: video games / mainstream software != all software.  There are very interesting software that are very specific and targeted at tiny audiences.  These typically have licenses costing $$$ and you don't see these on warez sites.  Why?  The audience is too small so *a)* pirates have no fame in cracking them for a non-existing audience and *b*) pirates often couldn't even *access* these software.  Also, if licensing managers have no use, how comes there are companies selling them to happy customers who themselves have happy customers using their copy-protected software?  I've *been* there...

Comment: @user98 I've never worked for a single enterprise (and that's what you're talking about there) where using pirated products was even considered - I mean just thinking about the consequences (oh and no support for it is also not something an enterprise would really consider). And why licensing managers are used? Because management without understanding the technical consequences is rather easy to convince (Oh we can avoid people stealing our software? Let's do that!). The consequences for paying customers are [not that entertaining](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403210.html).

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by having client server interaction.

When the client software is delivered to the the customer and that is registered with the Server Software then the date and time of the start of the client should be registered in the database.

We should make sure that the client software should not work with out connection to the server software.

The client software should have a code that should be in a position to disable to all the features at any instance of time by taking the server push instructions. Or the Server should have the control over the critical feature of the client software.

This one idea for doing the application.

Answer (score 2):

If client has whole source code and you application is stand alone and does not depend on any other server side component you cannot protect anything.

If your application uses server you can block it at server. If it does not you can create some small part of code that is very important for the application to function but this part will be downloaded from server.

Alternatively this part of code can be supplied without source code and obfuscated after compilation.